# Carbon or Cocoa notification when user changes a system shortcut

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, input, macos-carbon

I'm working on implementing some keyboard shortcuts for my app and running into a problem when they collide with system shortcuts (the ones set in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts).

A good example of the behavior I'd like to imitate is Xcode. Its Key Bindings settings will allow the user to set a shortcut for any action, except those already mapped in System Preferences. However, if the user later sets a shortcut in System Preferences, Xcode will show a warning at the bottom of the settings window saying that "a system shortcut may take precedence over this shortcut". The warning seems to show up immediately after I set a shortcut in System Preferences. So it would seem that Xcode is getting a notification that a new system shortcut has been set. Anyone know either what that notification might be, or how I could find out what it is?

Comment: You can register with both `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` and `[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` for all notifications, regardless of name or object, then log the notifications which happen when you change a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Thanks. I tried making a little app that listened to all notifications, both distributed and local to the app. Unfortunately no notifications are posted for system shortcut changes. That's why I was wondering about Carbon... most of the system shortcut stuff is only available in Carbon.